# Maven: Let SkinnyWars preserve some libraries

Tags: java, maven, war, ear, skinny-war

I am using maven to build an ear file with two EJBs and a few web applications. I'd like to use skinny wars, because more wars are likely to follow.

As I understood, the following will remove all *.jar files (except ejb jars) from the WEB-INF/lib directory of all war files:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>my.domain</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>war</type>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Scope: Provided for skinnies. -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>my.domain</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

[..]

 <configuration>
      <version>7</version>
      <defaultLitBundleDir>lib/</defaultLitBundleDir>
      <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
[..]
```

The problem I have is that will obviously also remove all [webjars](http://www.webjars.org/). Webjars are web libraries (css, JS, etc.) which are packaged inside jar files like this:

> With any Servlet 3 compatible container, the WebJars that are in the
>   WEB-INF/lib directory are automatically made available as static
>   resources. This works because anything in a META-INF/resources
>   directory in a JAR in WEB-INF/lib is automatically exposed as a static
>   resource.

Source: http://www.webjars.org/documentation#servlet3

I really like this idea. So now, when all jars are moved to myear!/lib/webjar, the containing files are not exposed anymore. :-(

I haven't found an option for skinnyWars to NOT exclude certain libraries (like org.webjars:*:*).

If there is another solution, I'd love to see your input.

Comment: No, it won't remove all JARs from the WAR. Only those that were specified as dependency in the EAR's POM. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html

Comment: Ahh okay. I just included the war again with dependency:type=pom, because of the DRY principle. Anyway, I found another solution, posting it in a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there was an easy solution. As you see from my updated answer, I had the (almost) same dependency of the war file twice: Once as `type=war`, another one as `type=pom`, so all dependencies were included in the ear and stripped from the war.

Now, I could just manually put the shared libraries there, but I was [thinking of DRY](https://blog.frankel.ch/dry-and-skinny-war/). So I wanted to go with the mentioned solution. Seems a bit hacky, but works flawlessly.

But some moments later, I clicked on the [wrong link in the webjars documentation for Servlet2](http://www.webjars.org/documentation#servlet2), which I am not using.

It works by having another dependency, which consists of only one Servlet. This servlet rewrites/passes requests to the corresponding files in `META-INF/resources`. I thought this may be working for my situation as well.

So I included the dependency seen on the servlet2 documentation and added the corresponding parts to the `web.xml` file. And not it's working as expected.